# How can i continually replace a word behind a set value in a string?

Tags: python

How can i continually replace the word behind a set value (in my example`_Number_`) in a string?

The text I want to replace appears to two times and looks like this in the textfile:

```
One_Number_ = "0"
if [ One_Number_ == "0" ]
```

So in this example I want to store the word "One" in a string. The idea is that this program runs multiple times so I need to work with the `_Number_`part of the string that is a set value (never changes) because I will continually replace the word behind `_Number_`.

With my current code I do not get out the `One`but instead I also get out the `if` on the second time it appears for instance.

```
with open(os.path.join('BuildWatchBundle.sh'), 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

with open(os.path.join('BuildWatchBundle.sh'), 'w') as file:
    for line in lines:
        if (line.__contains__('_Number_')):
            word = line.rsplit('_', 1)[0]
            print ("Word is: " + word)
```

How can i adjust my code so i can continually replace a word behind a set value in a string?

Updated code:

```
set_value = "_int_"
re_set = re.compile(r'(\w+)({})'.format(set_value))
ReplaceLower = ""
ReplaceUpper = ""

with open(os.path.join('text.txt'), 'r') as file:
   lines = file.read()
with open(os.path.join('text.txt'), 'w') as file:

    for pre, value in re_set.findall(lines):
        ReplaceUpper = pre
        ReplaceLower = pre.lower()

        if (lines.__contains__(ReplaceLower)):
            lines = line.replace (ReplaceLower, enteredNameFromShell.lower())
        elif (lines.__contains__(ReplaceUpper)):
            lines = line.replace (ReplaceUpper, enteredNameFromShell)

file.write(lines)
```

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by continually?

Comment: Why are you using `rsplit` instead of `split`? It seems as though you want what comes BEFORE the FIRST `_`.

Comment: @Rahul Meaning that i will continiously replace the word behind `_Number_` so each time i run the pythonscript a new word will be there.

Comment: @doctorlove exactly. I only want the word after the first _

Comment: The word after the first `_` is `Number_`

Comment: before* sorry, my mistake

Comment: Try `split` instead

Comment: Tried that. I still get the "if" and everything after until `One` on the second time that it appears

Comment: You need to improve your question to show more realistic examples of the input/output that you need. Add a short example of the source text, your search term, and what the resulting output should look like. The example should include as many different special cases as possible that need to be dealt with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `re.sub()` to replace all matching text in one go:

```
import re

set_value = "_Number_"
replace_with = "Two"

filename = 'input.txt'

with open(filename) as f_input:
    text = re.sub(r'(\w+)({})'.format(set_value), r'{}\2'.format(replace_with), f_input.read())

with open(filename, 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(text)
```

For your example text this would update your file as:

```
Two_Number_ = "0"
if [ Two_Number_ == "0" ]
```

---

To also list all of the matches before writing the new file and to add a bespoke replacement function:

```
import re

set_value = "_Number_"
filename = 'input.txt'
re_set = re.compile(r'(\w+)({})'.format(set_value))

def replace(re_match):
    values = {'one':'two', 'One':'Two', 'ONE':'TWO'}
    word = re_match.group(1)
    print('Word is', word)
    return '{}{}'.format(values[word], set_value)


with open(filename) as f_input:
    text = re_set.sub(replace, f_input.read())

with open(filename, 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(text)
```

So if your file contained:

```
One_Number_ = "0"
if [ One_Number_ == "0" ]

one_Number_ = "0"
if [ one_Number_ == "0" ]

ONE_Number_ = "0"
if [ ONE_Number_ == "0" ]
```

The output would now be:

```
Two_Number_ = "0"
if [ Two_Number_ == "0" ]

two_Number_ = "0"
if [ two_Number_ == "0" ]

TWO_Number_ = "0"
if [ TWO_Number_ == "0" ]
```

Just update the dictionary with any necessary conversions. Or use your own logic. `re_match.group(1)` contains the matching word. So you just need to build a suitable replacement string and return it. You could also add a `print(re_match.group(1))` to show you each of the matched words, rather than the second `findall()` loop.

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: How would u adjust the code if i want to store "One" before i replace it to a "Two" in a string and not just replace it straight away while reading the file?

Comment: Trying to somehow make it work with readlines() instead of read() instead. If i change it then the script does not run

Comment: It wont work with `readlines()` as that will produce a list of lines. You would have to execute the regular expression on each line rather than the whole text. It would be much slower.

Comment: Ok. The thing is that the reason why i want to get that word out in a string is so i can replace it on different places in the file. It's in the txt as lowercase and also upercase and this is the code i've done: `for pre, value in re_set.findall(text):
        ReplaceUpper = pre
        ReplaceLower = pre.lower()
        if (text.__contains__(ReplaceLower)):
            text = text.replace (ReplaceLower, enteredName.lower())
        elif (text.__contains__(ReplaceUpper)):
            text = text.replace (ReplaceUpper, enteredName)`
and then i write out `f_output.write(text)`

Comment: ...with this code the loop continues to go until the txt file increases to more than 1gb before i close the script

Comment: You can make the regular expression case insensitive: `re_set = re.compile(r'(\w+)({})'.format(set_value), re.I)`, it would then match `_NUMber` or `_number` or `_NUMBER_`

Comment: You can also add a function to handle each replacement in a bespoke manner if needed.

Comment: Its not _NUMber or _number or _NUMBER_ that are case insensitive. Its the word that i wont to store, in thise case "one" before "two" replaces it. Because on some places its "One" and others "one"

Comment: Also this "One" and "one" are not always behind `_Number_`

Comment: Then you need a function for the replacement, not `re.I`. It would give you what was matched and you can choose the logic on what to replace it with.

Comment: Alright. I tried to somehow combine read and readlines, and the for loop each line in text but that did not work as expected either

Comment: Does not work as intended, also i will keep adding numbers (in a strange order) so i cant write out "one" : "two" etc. Secondly it only finds the number if its behind `_Number_` but it should find the number everywhere on the txt file and replace it with lowercase or uppercase depnding on how the word getting replaced looks

Comment: You need to improve your question to show more realistic examples of input/output that you need. I keep trying to guess what you need.

Comment: Yea i understand and im sry for that. Check my updated code on the post to get an idea of what im trying to do. (That code doesnt work but u will see the logic) I take that word out that is behind `_Number_` and then i replace it all over the txt file with lowercase and uppercase

Comment: You shouldn't use `__contains__` like that, it should be `if '_Number_' in line:`.  Some input/output examples would still help. You say the could be elsewhere on a line, but there are no examples for this.

Comment: But some "One" are completely stand alone, not part of `_Number_`. So what i try to achieve is get the data from the first line before `_Number_`and then store that data in a string "One" so i can replace it everywhere with a new string called "Two" for instance

Comment: So what if the line contained the word `honey` or `lonely` ? Normally you need to use a regular expression to spot whole words only to avoid this problem. This is why an example would be helpful to try and spot possible delimiters.

Comment: That is why i use `if (lines.__contains__(ReplaceLower)):`then i replace it with my enteredword.lower() so it only replaces that word

Comment: Using `in` (or `__contains__` it is the same thing) would spot `one` in `honey` and your replace would give you `htwoy`.

Comment: Yea and i dunno how to combine this. I use ur for loop now where i get the correct word out and then i try to read through the txt file and see where i can find this word and replace it. In other words; get out the word before `_Number_`, store it in a string, read through the txtfile, replace that word (upper letter or lower letter) with the new word (Two for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions:

```
import re

lines = """
One_Number_ = "0"
if [ One_Number_ == "0" ]
"""

r = re.compile(r'(\w+)_Number_')
print r.findall(lines)
```

Output:

```
['One', 'One']
```

Documentation:

- Python `re` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html
- Regular expression syntax: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: `TypeError: must be str, not _sre.SRE_Pattern`

Comment: @Carlos That's not a very useful comment. Which line? Which version of python?